# wpf webbrowser control not applying css

Tags: jquery, wpf, c#-4.0

hi I am rendering xhtml/html/xml pages in web browser control using memory stream.
if I am applying this css to divide pages in column on body.
then It's not applying on control.

```
 <body  style=\"-webkit-column-width:800px; overflow:visible !important;
     -moz-column-width: 800px;    column-width: 800px; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; 
     -moz-column-gap: 0px; column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-rule: 0px solid #000;
     -moz-column-rule: 0px solid #000;column-rule: 0px solid #000; height:800px; 
      position:absolute; margin:0px; -moz-margin:0px;-webkit-margin:0px;
     display:block;\">");
```

I am not using url to render pages.
I am using memory stream or string.

Comment: for which control onto the page it's not applying?

Comment: Wrote WebBrowser control :P

Comment: WebBrowser control in wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor, you can write these lines of code in order to resolve issues with your CSS:

```
var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", fileName, GetBrowserEmulationMode());
```

Alternatively, you can read [this blog post](http://dumpcoding.blogspot.com/2011/05/add-css-file-to-browser-control-in.html). And [this forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cf66e0cd-ab6f-45b8-b230-1d78f26670d2/opening-links-from-wpf-webbrowser-control-in-default-browser-instead-of-ie?forum=wpf), that contains some hacks for your trouble.

Comment: thanks christain, I am using this code but not getting DomDocument.   and what parameter will be in createStyleSheet("",0)     mshtml.HTMLDocument CurrentDocument = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)WebBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
                mshtml.IHTMLStyleSheet styleSheet = CurrentDocument.createStyleSheet("", 0);
                                                                DomDocument is undefine